# Remove everything from Mac and reinstall OS X

Tags: macos, mac, install, bootable-disk

Is it possible to delete everything from my Mac and then install OS X from a bootable USB? I don't why but somehow AudioAUUC extension was modified a few months ago and my sound isn't working since then. That's why I would like remove everything and install a fresh OS X.

Comment: You could also boot from the recovery partition and delete and reinstall the OS

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily have to remove everything to repair OS X

Depending on OS X version you can just reboot holding the R key, to boot into the recovery partition. Alternatively you can hold alt/option to display current boot options and select your recovery partition.

Once in the recovery partition, you can use Disk Utility to erase your OS X partition if you want to wipe everything, or you can just select "Reinstall OS X" from the main menu. This will reinstall OS X system files and leave your home directory, settings, documents, etc alone. I'd recommend trying just the reinstall of OS X first, and if this doesn't work to fix your issue, proceed to erase your OS X partition and then reinstall OS X.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a backup of your files/settings
2. Boot into the OS X Installer

   *If you need to create a bootable USB installer, see the [Apple KB article](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201372)*
3. Open Disk Utility and erase the disk
4. Use the OS X Installer to install OS X